# How can I fix "responsive-design mode" problems for mobile devices (Wordpress theme)?

Tags: iphone, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am using a wordpress theme in "responsive-design mode".  Viewing website on iPad renders the way it should (including desktop, non-responsive), but viewing on iphone gets messy.  Can someone help me figure out how to duplicate the iPad style to the iPhone and all non-desktop devices; and delete the smartphone styling completely.  I am looking to duplicate the exact layout as the iPad for all mobile devices (just smaller versions).  The author of the theme told me to look in the "responsive-all.css" file and fix things there, but I'm having trouble since I'm not well versed in css.  Here is the link to the css. [responsive-all.css](http://www.gearmx.com/wp-content/uploads/responsive-all.css)

Any help is MUCH appreciated.  Thanks
Michael

Comment: If your site is gearmx.com then I see no issues with your mobile site.  It is working fine just as intended.  To squeeze what you see for tablet mode into a phone is really unrealistic.  The whole reason that it is different as it is now, is because it should be different.  

Can you show us some images of what you think is "messy"?  From what I can see, nothing is messy and you just don't like what the mobile phone size looks like, in which case you're kinda just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** : if you want to delete the mobile's view, just comment the end of the CSS file beginning with or delete and of course the following :

```
/*
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* MOBILE BOTH VIEWS
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
...
```

**Step 2** : Then change, the condition to get the same design for tablets/smartphones :

```
/*
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* TABLET PORTRAIT 
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/   @media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
```

After, I don't know what you want on this mobile/tablet view exactly.

Comment: Due to the complexity of fixing the responsive modes, I have opted to use the site "non-responsive".  However, when a member is logged into the site, the user cannot click on menus via an iPhone or iPad (the menu just flashes)...weird.  When a member isn't logged in, the menus work perfect. It's as if the "member login screen" in the header is conflicting.  This was the whole reason why I was trying to use the responsive mobile menus in the first place.  If anyone knows what may cause this please let me know.  Thanks.  Desktop versions work perfect.  The site is www.alexhaleyacademy.com

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your current viewport meta tag with the following will probably make the iPhone (and most other mobile devices) look like the iPad:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=768">
```